# How to get the data on a specific Polyline

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I want to show the Toast on a specific polyline coordinates, for example, in this code I want to show the Toast on that specific polyline, however, what happens is that onPolylineClick the Toast is showing the data that is last read by the program, in this case, the 'polylineClicker2()'.

The polyline is placed on its respective coordinates I have given, only the toast is doing what the program last read.

```
public void polylineClicker() {

        LatLng postition1  = new LatLng(14.601796, 121.006707);
        LatLng postition2  = new LatLng(14.601033, 120.998558);
        PolylineOptions popOption = new PolylineOptions()
                .add(postition1).add(postition2).width(5).color(Color.YELLOW).clickable(true);
        map.addPolyline(popOption);


        map.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Polyline near friends' house", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }
    public void polylineClicker2() {
        LatLng position1  = new LatLng(14.617106, 120.989924);
        LatLng position2  = new LatLng(14.616068, 120.990939);
        PolylineOptions popOption = new PolylineOptions()
                .add(position1).add(position2).width(5).color(Color.YELLOW).clickable(true);
        map.addPolyline(popOption);


        map.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Polyline near my house", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener` that you are setting on your `polylineClicker2` is overriding the one that you are setting on your `polylineClicker` (assuming that you are calling `polylineClicker` before `polylineClicker2`).

You need to create just one `GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener`, and as you need different behavior (different messages) you can use tags. Using your code:

```
public void polylineClicker() {
    LatLng position1  = new LatLng(14.601796, 121.006707);
    LatLng position2  = new LatLng(14.601033, 120.998558);
    PolylineOptions popOption = new PolylineOptions()
            .add(position1).add(position2).width(5).color(Color.YELLOW).clickable(true);
    map.addPolyline(popOption).setTag("Polyline near friends' house");
}

public void polylineClicker2() {
    LatLng position1  = new LatLng(14.617106, 120.989924);
    LatLng position2  = new LatLng(14.616068, 120.990939);
    PolylineOptions popOption = new PolylineOptions()
            .add(position1).add(position2).width(5).color(Color.YELLOW).clickable(true);
    map.addPolyline(popOption).setTag("Polyline near my house");
}
```

And set the `GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener` wherever you need, for example on your `onMapReady` before calling `polylineClicker` and `polylineClicker2`:

```
map.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, (String) polyline.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I put the map.setOnPOlylineClickListener on the onMapReady however, it gets a red line which says "Cannot resolve method 'makeText(rjj.manilapuvtravelcompanion_2nd.MainActivity, java.lang.Object, int)"

Comment: Added a cast to `String`, check now

Comment: I casted it to string, however when I click the polyline in my friends' house; it shows no tag but when I click the polyline near my house it shows the tag "Polyline near my house"

Comment: Could you show the code where you add the listener and call the functions?

Comment: Oh wait, it is working, it's just that the KML Layers I have added also get affected by the onClickListener which is weird. What I did is I called the polylines last and the KML Layers (polylines) first